# Swift Sprite-Kit - Position in corners

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

```
enemyFromCorner1.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
enemyFromCorner2.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
enemyFromCorner3.position = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
enemyFromCorner4.position = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
```

I want my enemies to be in all corners. What am I doing wrong?

I want 4 nodes to spawn in 4 corners. Upper-Left, Upper-Right, Lower-left, and Lower-Right, with SpriteKit and Swift.

Right now, I get them all in Lower-left corner.

And, based on this: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html
the code should be right.

Comment: What are you doing? Please provide more info

Comment: A Game. And I want 4 nodes to spawn in 4 corners. Upper-Left, Upper-Right, Lower-left, and Lower-Right, with SpriteKit and Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I sorted it on my own:

```
enemyFromCorner1.position = CGPoint(x: size.width, y: size.height)
enemyFromCorner2.position = CGPoint(x: size.width - size.width, y: size.height)
enemyFromCorner3.position = CGPoint(x: size.width, y: size.height - size.height)
enemyFromCorner4.position = CGPoint(x: size.width - size.width, y: size.height - size.height)
```